# Update item in BindableCollection with notify ICollectionView

Tags: wpf, listbox, caliburn, notify, icollectionview

Hi I bind collection from Caliburn Micro on ListBox control in view. Here is it.

```
public BindableCollection<UserInfo> Friends
{
    get { return _friends; }
    set
    {
        _friends = value;
        NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => Friends);
    }
}
```

ListBox items is type of UserInfo.

Hi I sort and group listbox items, I use CollectioView on this purpose.

When I initialize ListBox I sort and group items with this method.

```
private ICollectionView _currentView;

//...

private void SortContactList()
{
    _currentView = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(Friends);

    _currentView.GroupDescriptions.Add(new PropertyGroupDescription("TextStatus"));

    _currentView.SortDescriptions.Add(new SortDescription("TextStatus", ListSortDirection.Ascending));

    _currentView.SortDescriptions.Add(new SortDescription("Nick", ListSortDirection.Ascending));
}
```

TextStatus and Nick are properties of userInfo class.

When I update values of item in bindable collection Friend I would like have a way how notify collection view about this change. Because I need move item to right/good group.

for example

```
Friend[0].TextStatus = "Ofline" -> is in offline group
```

I change value on online;

```
Friend[0].TextStatus="Online" -> move in online group
```

and here I want notify collection view (_currentView) about change on Friends collection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same issue when I created an application that had a table with the Rating column.
I wondered why row doesn't move up when I change rating, and in the end I used the `Refresh` method.

For your example:

```
Friend[0].TextStatus="Online" -> move in online group
_currentView.Refresh();
```

Fortunately, performance problems didn't occur, so now I use this solution in similar situations.

Comment: Hi, thank for feedback this solution I use, but it cause problem which I describe here:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4986255/sort-and-group-listitems-in-a-wpf-listbox-groupitem-collapse-and-expand